# Prevent PySimpleGUI InputText event from executing while element is disabled when using FocusIn bind?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

My GUI has an InputText box with default text that is to be cleared upon focus; however, the InputText is disabled until a ListBox selection is made. Even if a ListBox selection has not been made and the InputText box is disabled, the default text will still be cleared if the InputText box is clicked. Is there a way to prevent this? Or to check if the InputText is disabled when clicked?

Sample Code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    layout = [[sg.Input("Search", s=(30,1), disabled=True, k="-SEARCH-")],
              [sg.Listbox(values=["One", "Two", "Three"], s=(30,5), k='-LIST-', enable_events=True)]]

    window = sg.Window("Test", layout, use_default_focus=False, finalize=True)
    window['-SEARCH-'].bind('<FocusIn>', '_Focus')

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
            break
        if event == '-LIST-':
            window['-SEARCH-'].Update(disabled=False)
        if event == '-SEARCH-' + "_Focus":
            window['-SEARCH-'].Update("")
            window.refresh()

    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Add one more option `use_readonly_for_disable=False` in `sg.Input`, or it will be only readonly, not really `disabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Jason Yang's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72089201/prevent-pysimplegui-inputtext-event-from-executing-while-element-is-disabled-whe?noredirect=1#comment127376353_72089201), the solution was to simply add the following to my Input declaration:

```
use_readonly_for_disable=False
```

Such that:

```
layout = [[sg.Input("Search", s=(30,1), disabled=True, use_readonly_for_disable=False, k="-SEARCH-")],
          [sg.Listbox(values=["One", "Two", "Three"], s=(30,5), k='-LIST-', enable_events=True)]]
```